# Importing c++ projects to eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, import

I use eclipse Neon from a ubuntu 15.04 virtual box. 
I want to run medical image reconstruction framework gadgetron from https://github.com/gadgetron/gadgetron. I downloaded zip file and extracted the gadgetron code zip folder into eclipse workspace. The folder structure shown below:

[image]

Through menu New -> Makefile project with Existing Code, I imported the gadgetron code into eclipse IDE. The eclipse screen looks like this.

[image]

When I try to build the project, I get an error `make:*** No rule to make targe 'all'. Stop.`

How can I build and run this project in eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [README](https://github.com/gadgetron/gadgetron/blob/master/README.md) of the project. You imported as an project with an existing makefile. Eclipse looks for the Makefile in the root directory of the project and in this case simply couldn't find one. You can either tell Eclipse to use a specific Makefile or create one in the root of the project.

Edited: Adjusted answer to show final solution.

Comment: As stated in README file, I created a build folder and run `cmake` and `make install` commands. The build folder is also imported as part of project folder.

Comment: Eclipse calls the make instruction in the main folder of your project. If the project builds the Makefile in the build folder you can either redirect Eclipse to the correct Makefile or simply include only the build folder as the project in Eclipse. But the Readme says `cmake ../` - if I'm not mistaken this should still place the Makefile in your project root folder.

Comment: Thanks. I import build folder of the project. Also I configure project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Builder settings -> Makefile generation -> Generate makefiles automatically. Now I can build the project without errors.